# mdadm: RAID gone after reboot, partitions gone, service masked

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

Some weeks ago **I set up a software RAID 1 with mdadm**, consisting of two 2TB WD Red HDDs, as a backup medium (Debian Stable). Everything works, I hooked up everything for it to come up after a reboot, with UUIDs, tested it, not my first rodeo.

Today I did shut down the server gracefully, to change some fans. **After reboot the RAID is gone.**

Ok, lets check:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>
```

Strange, /dev/md0 was not assembled.

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdf (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sde (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
```

Well, the RAID should consist of /dev/sde and /dev/sdf. But no superblocks found there?

```
# gdisk -l /dev/sde
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sde: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: WDC WD20EFRX-68E
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): FE89DB52-F870-403A-9211-1E716ADD10A1
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 2048, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3907027087 sectors (1.8 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Same for /dev/sdf, what happened? Where did the partition go?
smartctl says the disks are ok, and both failing at the same time would be unprobable anyway.

Adding up to this strange behavior, the mdadm service is not running, even masked:

```
# systemctl status mdadm.service 
● mdadm.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mdadm.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

**What could have happened here?** Even more important to me than recovering the data is to understand what happened and to make sure this does not happen again. After all what's worse than an unreliable RAID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the issue using this advice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484532/429161

In effect I destroyed the GPT table and recreated the array, which worked and made the data accessible again. I am still not sure what happened, but I have to assume I ran into a problem with adding whole disks to an array, where the former GPT was not nulled:

> Another important argument is that some mainboards may delete your RAID superblocks if you use whole disk devices and are not super careful with wiping them when adding disks to a RAID array that once were GPT devices.

Comment: Rather than adding an entire disk to your array, consider creating a single partition spanning the entire disk and making the RAID from that

Comment: Before this incident I didn't know there was any downside using the whole disk. Now I know better...