# Ubuntu Server mdam device disappeared after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I have a server (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) running a software RAID 1 with mdadm, consisting of 2 WD Red disks.  After booting the server, a Windows client couldn’t find the Samba share.  I logged into the server and ran:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 930.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk
```

The drives were there, but the **md0 device disappeared**! I was kind of scared.  I looked at the status of the RAID:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
unused devices: <none>
```

The I searched the log for md0:

```
$ grep "md0" /var/log/syslog
Mar 29 08:44:07 saturno systemd[1]: dev-md0.device: Job dev-md0.device/start timed out.
Mar 29 08:44:07 saturno systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/md0.
Mar 29 08:44:07 saturno systemd[1]: dev-md0.device: Job dev-md0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 29 08:55:04 saturno systemd[1]: dev-md0.device: Job dev-md0.device/start timed out.
Mar 29 08:55:04 saturno systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/md0.
Mar 29 08:55:04 saturno systemd[1]: dev-md0.device: Job dev-md0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

I found this [article here in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1642292/mdadm-raid-gone-after-reboot-partitions-gone-service-masked), by [xalib](https://superuser.com/users/1169028/xalib) that had almost the same issue.  I ran this command to assemble the RAID array, looking at the drives in the system, and showing a verbose response:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: Devices UUID-c5d7f13c:4d9bc7ac:bff90942:065235e7 and UUID-c5d7f13c:4d9bc7ac:bff90942:065235e7 have the same name: /dev/md0
mdadm: Duplicate MD device names in conf file were found.
```

I had to remove the duplicated device using:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

This is weird because this configuration had been running for almost 2 weeks.  When I ran the command again it worked fine:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000476)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 2 drives.
```

**The md0 device was up again!**  I tried to reach the shares with the Windows machine, but the weren’t ready.  I ran:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda    931.5G                   disk
├─sda1     1G vfat              part  /boot/efi
└─sda2 930.5G ext4              part  /
sdb      5.5T linux_raid_member disk
└─md0    5.5T ext4              raid1
sdc      5.5T linux_raid_member disk
└─md0    5.5T ext4              raid1
```

The RAID was up, but it had no mount point.  I had to mount it manually:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/share
```

And then again:

```
mauricio@saturno:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda    931.5G                   disk
├─sda1     1G vfat              part  /boot/efi
└─sda2 930.5G ext4              part  /
sdb      5.5T linux_raid_member disk
└─md0    5.5T ext4              raid1 /media/share
sdc      5.5T linux_raid_member disk
└─md0    5.5T ext4              raid1 /media/share
```

I checked the shares, and they were running just fine.

The question is:  **How do I find out what made the RAID fail?**  I don't want to happen again.